# Add localization-language support to a BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

It is possible to add to a bash script language support? I have a bash script with some string, and I want it internationalize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try giving this a read: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/internationalizing-those-bash-scripts

Comment: That's funny, I just googled "bash script i18n" and found the exact same link. +1

Comment: Tis one of the things I love about Stack Overflow. If I don't know the answer to something, I look it up and I get to learn about it too.

Comment: Thanks Mike, exactly what I want.